# KMP Algorithm : Worst Case

Tags: algorithm

I have a question regarding the worst case running time for Knuth Morris Pratt Algorithm for String Matching:

Let's say the T = AAAAB and P = AB.

In this case, the prefix table is:

#             P            Sk-D

0               A           0

1               B           0

As I scan through T and compare values of P with it:
AAAAB
AB
There is a partial match at Cell#0. Since the skip distance for Cell#0 for P is 0, we move P to the next cell:
AAAAB
  AB

Hence, the same scenario will repeat three times (6 comparisons) until T matches the substring , "AB" in P (2 more comparisons). In all there were 8 comparisons = Length of P * Length of T - Length of T = 5 * 2 - 2 = 8 = O(mn) - O(m) = O(mn). Obviously, this is not O(m+n), the worst case bound for the KMP algorithm.

What am I doing wrong? I feel my prefix table is incorrect, but I cannot see any other values in the prefix table if I follow the definition of "longest suffix in P that is also a prefix in P".

I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you!

Comment: "Obviously, this is not O(m+n)" -- not true.  4=2*2, but it does not imply that 4 != 2+2 also.

Comment: It's enough for the number of steps in an O(m+n) method to be bounded by am+bn+c with a, b and c all *arbitrary* constants.  Thus, no individual instance contains enough information to be a counterexample to (or, BTW, a proof of) a running time claim.  To show a counterexample, you would need to find a *family of inputs parameterised by n and/or m* that take worse than O(m+n) time.